# How to automatically grep the corresponding author name using authblk.sty

Tags: authblk

Using `authblk.sty`, I need to automatically grep the corresponding author name string. But I don't how to execute this concept. I think `etoolbox` is helpful for this logic.

`corresauthor` is the key to capture the author name and put the `*` symbol on the author name like `Keith Lindsey2*`.

`corresaddress={address text here}` specifies the name and address to be printed on the particular call out place.

My tex coding is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}   
\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2,**corresauthor,corresaddress={is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology in the School of Biological and Biomedical Science sat Durham University, UK}**]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil[2]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

My required output is:

[image]

Please suggest how to get this output using this concept.

Comment: The package `authblk` isn't suitable for this issue. I think you can achieve your request with the package `scrlayer`.

Comment: Any other package is to be merged the authblk style file and execute above mentioned coding

Comment: It seems you are asking for (more or less) the same output here and in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220055/how-to-print-the-corresponding-author/220203#220203.