# How to print the corresponding author

Tags: titles, authblk

I am using the authblk style file. I want to print the corresponding author and address to the left of the complete list of authors (and in addition to this list - so the list should also contain the corresponding author). Moreover, the corresponding author should be marked by an asterisk in the complete list of authors.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\makeatletter
\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 50pc%
\vbox{\hbox to 0pt{\vbox to 0pt{\vskip -40pc%
\begin{minipage}[!b]{10pc}
{\@correspondence\par}%
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{12pt}
\begin{minipage}[!b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
%      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{Journal Title}
\author[1*]{Junli Liu}
\affil{address one}
\correspondence{Junli Liu\newline correspondence author address to be printed here}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

What I would like to have instead is something like:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}


\begin{document}

\title{Journal Title}
\author[1,corauthor,coraddress={corresponding address here}]{Junli Liu}
\affil{address one}


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The output of my current code and my requirements are illustrated here:

[image]

How can I modify `\author` to work as required?

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your question. Do you want the author to be written below the address? Could you elaborate the details of your question?

Comment: I edit and save my question. Kindly provide the solution

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you would like to have a command that 1) marks the corresponding author with a star, 2) sends the name and the affiliation of that author to the `\correspondence` command such that this information is displayed on the left, and 3) additionally behaves like the ordinary `\author` and `\affil` commands?

Comment: Yes... Your understanding is absolutely wright. If you have any solution for this logic... Please provide the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the code you already have, you could achieve your desired output as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\makeatletter
\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 50pc%
\vbox{\hbox to 0pt{\vbox to 0pt{\vskip -40pc%
\begin{minipage}[!b]{10pc}
{\@correspondence\par}%
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{12pt}
\begin{minipage}[!b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
%      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\corauthor}[4]{\author[#4]{#1$^*$}\affil[#4]{#3}\correspondence{#1\newline #2}}

\begin{document}

\title{Journal Title}
\author[1]{First author}
\affil[1]{address one}
\corauthor{Junli Liu}{corresponding address}{address two}{2}
\author[3]{Third author}
\author[2]{Fourth author with same affil as corresponding one}
\affil[3]{address three}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

So instead of writing `\author[1,corauthor,coraddress={corresponding address here}]{Junli Liu}`, you would have to write `\corauthor{Junli Liu}{corresponding address}{address two}{2}` with this solution. The arguments of the command `\corauthor` are first the author's name, second the author's corresponding address, third the author's normal address, and fourth the index of the author's affiliation. As you can see in the example code, you can then use this index to refer to the same (normal) affiliation for other authors as well (e.g., for the fourth author in the code above).

Comment: Your solution is correct but corresponding address is different from the author affiliation in such cases. So we need to capture the separate input value. Otherwise the solution is good.

Comment: @Vetri I modified the answer to also capture separate corresponding address and normal affiliation.

Comment: I got the solution for my required output from your end. But If it is possible to declare the syntax this way "coraddress={cor address here}" because I push to create pre-defined tex file structure. The tex file is used to another process. Suppose, If you know any kind of solution for this requirement please provide. But now, i am using your logic...