# How does one indicate the corresponding author when using the authblk package?

Tags: authblk

This question is not a duplicate of [How to print the corresponding author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220055/how-to-print-the-corresponding-author), because that question is asking specifically how to make the corresponding author's name appear to the left of the complete list of authors, while also appearing in the complete list of authors.

I'd like to know the simplest, most standard way to indicate the corresponding author when using the authblk package.  I've googled a fair amount and have not found the answer.  If it's relevant, I'll be using the titlepage option, as in `\documentclass[titlepage]{article}.`

Here's a minimal example where the corresponding author is not indicated.  So I'd like to know how to alter this to indicate the corresponding author.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians in weak life-forms}

\author[1]{Darth Vader}
\author[2]{Darth Sidious}

\affil[1]{%
  Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, 
  The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{%
  Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power Building, The Works, Coruscant}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

The following code produces the screenshot later on, a screen of the log is attached as well.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians in weak
life-forms}

\author[1]{Darth Vader\thanks{corresponding author}}
\author[2]{Darth Sidious}

\affil[1]{%
    Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, 
The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{%
    Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power
Building, The Works, Coruscant}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]
You can see the number 1 is repeated as a superscript.

If I add \listfiles to the document, here is the log I get:
[image]

Comment: Make a full minimal example. As far as I know, authblk does not have anything build in to do this. But by any means, consult the manual.

Comment: Ok, just added a minimal example.  I read the authblk manual and didn't find the answer.  But authblk seems popular, and usually when you submit a paper you are supposed to indicate the corresponding author, so I think there must be some standard way that people do it.

Comment: Normally if a journal supports latex they provide a template for you to use. If they do not, they are probably going to completely rewrite what you submit anyway. So IMO it is not worth spending too much time on.

Comment: I have a template for a preprint series, we use authblk, but also a different interface for marking the corresponding author kwhich we do not use that much), it us just using `\thanks` in a certain manner AFAIR

Comment: `\author[1]{Darth Vader\thanks{nag me with your question}}`

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried this previously but the output I get has a repeated superscript 1, as shown in the picture I just added.

Comment: @daleif some conference abstract submissions (for example) expect camera-ready output and just stick the PDFs together.

Comment: The footnotemarker should be an asterisk `*`, not a number.

Comment: @Johannes_B How do I make the footnotemarker be an asterisk? Edit: Oh, perhaps with \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

Comment: @ChrisH then of course they should provide a template to ensure a common look and feel

Comment: @daleif, it would be nice if they did.  The examples I have in mind don't.

Comment: @ChrisH then you should complain to them, then at least next time perhaps they'll have better focus on it. But also remember that more often than not conference organizers do not know much about latex. If you're lucky they have someone helping that do, but often they don't. But if no one tells them that this can be done much better, how are hey ever going to improve?

Comment: In your very first example, replace the orginal vader line with mine, compile. Do you get an asterisk? You should. If not, something dodgy is going on, please add `\listfiles` to your document and show us the log file.

Comment: @Johannes_B In my very first example, if I replace the original vader line with yours, and compile, I do not get an asterisk.  I added the log file to the question.

Comment: I think your own reply, to use `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` is the best answer to the question.  Perhaps you could post an answer your own question (I'd vote for it).

Comment: @Johannes_B Somehow the problem seems to stem from the fact that I'm using the titlepage option, as in \documentclass[titlepage]{article}.  When I remove that option, I get the asterisk, as desired.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I removed that option because i didn't want an extra page. I immediately fogot that. Let me look closer.

Comment: I never noticed, that `titlepage` does not change the footnote marker. You can use the redefiniotn you posted earlier.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you for your help, I answered the question but if you'd like to submit an answer I'd accept your version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using `\thanks` , but if you are using the titlepage option (as in `\documentclass[titlepage]{article}`) then you should include the line `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` in the header to make the footnote marker be an asterisk.  We can also place the line `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` after \maketitle, to undo the global change.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians in weak life-forms}

\author[1]{Darth Vader \thanks{Corresponding author}}
\author[2]{Darth Sidious}

\affil[1]{%
  Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, 
  The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{%
  Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power Building, The Works, Coruscant}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to reset the footnote counter after the titlepage, right now, the change is global.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, would I do that by placing the line \setcounter{footnote}{0} immediately after the \maketitle line?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` after maketitle. I wasn't clear, sorry.

Comment: How to do it with acmart class?

Comment: This doesn't work with acmart class. I am trying to use \thanks within \author tag and its not working

Answer (score 14):

This is more a workaround than an official solution I guess. But depending on the journal's author-guidelines for your manuscript this formatting might look  more appropriate.
**It includes the indicator for the corresponding author as an affiliation.**

Example code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians in weak life-forms}

\author[1,*]{Darth Vader}
\author[2]{Darth Sidious}

\affil[1]{Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power Building, The Works, Coruscant}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: Darth Vader, darth@vader.deathstar}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Example picture:

[image: latex-example-affil]

Answer (score 2):

I found this question when googling for setting corresponding authors in ACM templates. This is how to set corresponding authors in an ACM template:

```
\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{\institution{Affiliation}}
\email{email}
\authornote{Corresponding authors}

\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{\institution{Affiliation}}
\email{email}
\authornotemark[1]

\author{Author 3}
\affiliation{\institution{Affiliation}}
\email{email}
```

Here, author 1 and 2 are both set as corresponding authors, but author 3 isn't. Further explanation can be found here: https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf

[image: corresponding authors]
[image: corresponding authors footnote]

Comment: It is not working with ACM CSUR

Answer (score 1):

For me this solution taken from [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25061) worked for an `elsarticle` document:

```latex
\author[affiliation]{Corresponding Author Name\corref{cor1}}
\ead{Corresponding Author Email Address}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
```