# Indicate corresponding author in llncs tempate

Tags: titles, author, lncs, affiliation

According to [the Springer's guidelines](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/svproc/guidelines/Springer_Guidelines_for_Authors_of_Proceedings_CS.pdf), I am requred to use llncs documentclass (as in [the template](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip)) and to indicate the corresponding author.

Unfortunately neither the guidelines, the template nor [this instruction](http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/llncs.pdf) covers how may I do it in the llncs documentclass.

Of course I can provide e-mail with my affiliation, but there are other authors from my institute. Also [I may claim that there is a *Corresponding author: foo@bar.com institute*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/379841/123888) and (despite of an evident violation of the semantics) I would go that way the affiliations were not automatically enumerated. I believe the corresponding author should be indicated more clearly than the biggest superscript number.
[The `\thanks` macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310209/123888) also is not what I expect as it results in a footnote, not a part of the title.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you found your answer. If someone else stumbles upon this question, here is what they need to do.

First, add the following package.

```
\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym}
```

Then, add it within the \author command.

```
\author{John Smith \Letter\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
```

I got this from the following webpage: [LaTex forum](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10276)

Comment: I abused the semantics.

Answer (score 1):

One option that I like very much and want to add to the pool of answers is using package `fontawesome5`. This solution compiles also with [Tectonic](https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/en-US/)

```latex
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\title{Runtime load-shifting of distributed controllers across networked devices}

\author{Angelo Filaseta\inst{1}\orcidID{0009-0004-6797-6814} \and
Danilo Pianini\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0002-8392-5409}\faIcon{envelope}}

\institute{
    Alma Mater Studiorum---Università di Bologna,
    47522 Cesena (FC), Italy
    \email{
        angelo.filaseta@studio.unibo.it, \faIcon{envelope} danilo.pianini@unibo.it
    }
}
```

result:
[image: rendered icon]

Comment: Similar approach to mine, but the symbol more intuitive.  At least for people familiar with history of our culture, as no one uses envelopes to send e-mails. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was an obvious abuse of semantics:

```
\author{Name1\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0001-2345-6789}$\spadesuit$ \and
        Name2\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0002-3456-7891} \and
        Name3\inst{1,2}\orcidID{0000-0002-3456-7892}
}
%
\authorrunning{Name1 et al.}
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{Institute1, Somewhere \and
           Institute2, Somewhere else\\
           $\spadesuit$ Corresponding author: \email{foo@bar.com}
}
```